# UITableView's textLabel.text position is not center in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need to set the three line of `detailTextLabel` in my `UITableView`.

So i set following code in my `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

After i set that , my cell.TextLabel.text position is happening like following pic.

[image]

I want that `cell.textLabel.`text in center, not in top.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextLabel would currently yet be with a height for One Line.

SubClass a UITableViewCell and reset the Frame of the TextLabel.

```
@implementation UINewTableViewCell
- (void) layoutSubviews {
     [super layoutSubviews];
     CGFloat aHeight = 100.0; // Set height according your requirement.
     self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, aHeight);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the frame of the label so it is the same as `detailTextLabel`'s, e.g.:

```
CGRect tempFrame = [[cell textLabel] frame];
tempFrame.size.height = [[cell detailTextLabel] frame].size.height;
[[cell textLabel] setFrame:tempFrame];
```

This should equalize their heights and center your string vertically.